# Show sales grouped per month in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to show sales grouped per month, to show something like:

```
201001 10000
201002 13000
201003 11000
201004 8000
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
SELECT [Transaction details].[Sales volume LOC]
FROM [Transaction details]
GROUP BY Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]);
```

I get the error message: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Sales volume LOC' as part of an aggregate function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you do not have the column `[Sales volume LOC]` in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause. If you want the totals for each month then you should add the `[Sales volume LOC]` to the `sum()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) as [Year],
  Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]) as [Month],
  sum([Transaction details].[Sales volume LOC]) as Total
FROM [Transaction details]
GROUP BY year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]), Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD])
ORDER BY year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]), Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]);
```

Comment: Thank you! But this displays sales per month. How do I display sales per year AND month ORDERED BY date from early to late?

Comment: @user1283776 You could use the `year` function, see my edit.  Or you could use `format` and format the date in the way that you want to display.

Comment: It seems to be working! But I get two input boxes when I run it: "Enter Parameter Value / Year" and "Enter Parameter Value / Month". Do you know how I can avoid getting those input boxes?

Comment: @user1283776 see my edit, MS Access does not seem to like aliases being using in the order by clause.